# Different margins with different length text in tikz node with align=center

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, hyphenation

Why are the margins different in the two nodes in this code? I would expect (and like) them to be the same.

Secondly, (and possibly related), why is the text hyphenated? This isn't normally desired for centred text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node [draw, yshift=-5cm, text width=20cm, align=center]
    at (current page.north) {\lipsum*[1]};
  \node [draw, yshift=-10cm, text width=20cm, align=center]
    at (current page.north) {\lipsum*[2]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: To me this seems more like an accident. Each line has a different width. It just so happens that the widths of the lines in the lower node a smaller than the ones in the upper node because then the nodes are more evenly filled. If you choose `text width=19cm`, the situation is reversed. BTW, what's the purpose of `overlay` here?

Comment: @marmot, overlay was just in case it was relevant as it's in my actual problem. I don't think it makes a difference though. I think the actual problem is that `align=center` seems to try and make all lines of equal length. So the margins vary wildly depending on the length of text. I need to test more and will provide a more obvious mwe.

Comment: @marmot, Oh. I just need to read the documentation more closely. I am looking for `align=flush center` instead of `align=center`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I am looking for in the `tikz` manual (of all places…).

I need `align=flush center` instead of `align=center`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm]
  \node (a) [draw, text width=20cm, align=center] {\lipsum*[1]};
  \node (b) [draw, text width=20cm, align=flush center, below=of a] {\lipsum*[1]};
  \node (c) [draw, text width=20cm, align=center, below=of b] {\lipsum*[2]};
  \node (d) [draw, text width=20cm, align=flush center, below=of c] {\lipsum*[2]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

I would not rely on the `lipsum` package for such kind of test. The package `blindtext` gives you a better feeling of how a text field looks like in the desired language. If in addition the package `babel` is loaded and the correct language is set, both your problems are gone. The text fields are evenly filled (ok, that's not a real surprise because unfortunately the printed text is just repeated) and there are no hyphens anymore.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node [draw, yshift=-5cm, text width=20cm, align=center]
    at (current page.north) {\blindtext};
  \node [draw, yshift=-10cm, text width=20cm, align=center]
    at (current page.north) {\blindtext[2]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the lipsum paragraphs were chosen for length not content. You haven't really answered the question. I am going to make a more obvious mwe showing the issue.